# Best way to approach loading a class from a comma delimited file

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, classloader, csv

I am a fairly new to objective-c and to object oriented programming in general and have a theoretical, stylistic type question.  What I want to do is load a table of classes with entries from a comma delimited file.  The data in the file consists many entries made up of a short key followed by several string values, all delimited by commmas.

There are a million ways to do this but I'm asking what would be the way which would be best from a strictly theoretical point of view.  I'd like to stay away from any sort of XML coding for the moment but will probably eventually convert to that format once I get an entry program together.

I could use a function to get the 'next record' and pass a structure in and out of the function, create a new instance of the class, load it up from the structure, then add it into an array.  I'd use the stringWithContentsOfFile method to load the file into a string initially then use string functions and some pointers to march through the file to return the structure elements which I would then load into the class.

Does this seem like a reasonable way to do this in objective-c or is there a better method which is perhaps more theoretically sound which would work at least as well?

Answer (score 4):

You have a CSV file, and you want to read it?  [There's some code for that](http://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser).

The simplest approach would be something like:

```
#import "CHCSV.h"

NSString * csvFile = ...; //path to the CSV file
NSError * error = nil;
NSArray * contents = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:csvFile
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];
if (contents == nil) {
    NSLog (@"Error %@", error);
} else {
    for (NSArray * row in contents) {
        NSLog(@"CSV fields in this line: %@", row);
        // "row" contains all the fields (as NSStrings) that were present
        // on this line of CSV
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a nice piece of code.  A little compact for an old COBOLer but pretty nice.  I had considered building an 'class' around the input file and using 'methods' to extract what I needed.  One method to load it into an NSSTRING... a different method to extract the next row into anther string... another method to get the first value in the current row... etc....   Is that pretty much overkill?

Comment: @Joe it depends on what your goal is with the code.  When writing `CHCSVParser`, my goal was to make it as simple to use as possible, so in addition to the event-driven parsing option (see the project for info on how that works), I also added this stuff to make it a one-line call.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm probably going to try it both ways (one using the code you supplied) and another maybe more formal version just to see the advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: @Dave DeLong hope you don't mind, put the error stuff in there so I can remember how it works when I can't remember obj-c at all.

Comment: And while we're here, `NSString *csvFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filenameNO-EXTENSION" ofType:@"csv"];` and also, the encoding must be UTF8 and LF's should be LF only. Other things might work too, didn't test nor read.

Comment: @Yar sure, but only if the CSV file is a bundled app resource.  Also, `CHCSVParser` understands any file encoding if you can specify it, and tries to guess if you can't.  As for the newline, anything that's part of `[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]` is recognized as a newline.  So `CRLF` is *two* lines.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: excellent. It all works nicely and saved me some lifting. Thanks

Comment: @Yar @DaveDeLong Actually, the way the error’s being checked does not conform to standard error programming practices in Cocoa. @DaveDeLong Does CHCSVParser follow Cocoa conventions?

Comment: @Bavarious As best as I know how, yes :) (and if you find anything that's not consistent with Cocoa conventions, let me know and I'll happily change it)

Comment: @Bavarious ...and that's an example of where I wasn't following conventions. I just pushed a change to github to fix that. Thanks!

Comment: @Bavarious, thanks for correcting that. I guessed that `error` not being null would take precedence, but conventions are indeed arbitrary.  Is there a link to this convention? Also, do you have to check `== nil` instead of just `if (contents)`... Thanks!

Comment: @Yar the convention is that since the `NSError**` is optional, it's just metadata to describe what happens when the return value indicates a failure. You should always check the return value before checking the error, because the error is not guaranteed to have the same value as what it was originally set to.

Comment: @Yar Checking the return value before the error object is documented in the Error Handling Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html

Comment: Thanks @Bavarious, @Dave DeLong, I see it now: "you should always check that the return value is nil or NO before attempting to do anything with the NSError object." And other stuff that I didn't know ;)